# Translate priority

Tags: magento2, localisation

Magento has 4-5 ways to translate and haven't good explanation of translation priority.

**Translates can be**

> - in themes
> - in modules
> - in translate package
> - in sub folders of themes/modules

There is my csv:

```
"Summary","Сводка","theme","frontend/ThemeVendor/theme-name"
"Summary","Обзор","module","Magento_Checkout"
"Summary","Заголовок","module","Magento_Review"
```

**Add: Magento 2 in some cases can't translate phrases.
Translate package helps...**

So, my config is

> - ru_RU.csv in the theme
> - in the app/i18n//ru_RU/*

Magento use the **last one** translation independent of module was been specified, if in CSV has not theme's translation.
I suppose Magento ignore CSV's 3rd column
for example

> "Summary","Заголовок","module","Magento_Review"
>   "Summary","Обзор","module","Magento_Checkout"

All translation will be 'Обзор'

Is there exist any `'academic'` solution to apply correct translate phrases to corresponding module's templates (instead of it's changing)?

Comment: The top priority for translation in Magento is the **`INLINE TRANSLATION`**, which is found in **Stores** >> **Configuration** >> **Advanced** >> **Developer** >> **Translate Inline**. Well, very nice question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is a little bit older already, but the default order of translation loading is defined in `\Magento\Framework\Translate::loadData` and is as follows (changed [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/38d4e24b83f1a7bd230ca82db0edb0b4a6716df8) in Oct., 2016):

- Module translations
- Language packs
- Theme translations
- Database translations

[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate.php#L218) you have the current status on 2.4 develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, translation works in the following order

1. module translations
2. theme translation
3. translation package (language pack)
4. database translation (Inline translation)